# How to choose a keyboard layout without rotating all options

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I am new to Linux and start with the Mint. I use three keyboard layouts (Eng, Rus, Fr), but only two of them are of everyday use. In Windows, I was using the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to switch between the main two layouts (Eng and Rus), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to rotate all three. Is it possible to implement the same in Cinnamon? I

Answer (score 0):

[image: toggle keyboardlayout]

As shown in the Image, you can create a custom Keyboard shortcut in the Keyboard settings. You give the Shortcut a name and point to the script you are gonna create. They you'll assign the Key Capslock to it.

for rotating betwen the two you can create a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This shell script is PUBLIC DOMAIN. You may do whatever you want with it.

TOGGLE=$HOME/.toggle

if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
    touch $TOGGLE
    setxkbmap en
    rm $TOGGLE
    setxkbmap ru
fi
```

(don't forget to `chmod +x` the script to make it executable)

For rotating between three commands, someone [at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637920/id-like-to-assign-a-bashscript-to-a-key-in-linux-to-toggle-between-multible-com) answered that question.

Here's your bash script for switching between three or more languages:

```
# Script that rotates between English, Russian, French, and Finnish keyboards

# Name of the state file
state_file=$HOME/.keyboard_state

# Ensure that the state file exists; initialize it with 0 if necessary.
[ -f "$state_file" ] || printf '0\n' > "$state_file"

# Read the next keyboard to use
read state < "$state_file"

# Set the keyboard using the current state
case $state in
    0) setxkbmap en ;;
    1) setxkbmap ru ;;
    2) setxkbmap fr ;;
    3) setxkbmap fi ;;
esac

# Increment the current state.
# Could also use state=$(( (state + 1) % 4 ))
state=$((state + 1))
[ "$state" -eq 4 ] && state=0

# Update the state file for the next time the script runs.
printf '%s\n' "$state" > "$state_file"
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the idea. But I have a trouble with the setxkbmap command. When I run it as setxkbmap us or setxkbmap ru even from the terminal, not from the script, something happens with the  standard keyboard manager: the layout icon disappears from the panel (right bottom), and the shortcuts, e.g., Ctrl+Shift, do not work any more, until I restart. I have tried man setxkbmap, but have no idea. Can you help with it?